# How to access author data from header action

Tags: actions, user-meta

I am adding a function to the header:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'mine');
function mine() {
  global $authordata;
  $avatar_url = get_avatar_ur($authordata->user_email);
  // ....
}
```

But I am getting the error: `trying to get property of non-object`.
I guess this is because I am in the header and not inside the post.

How can I access the authordata data from the header, and only when in a post page?

Comment: Try this http://pastebin.com/bxhm2qnZ

Comment: Hi @SamuelElh , your code works. If you put it as an answer and explain it a bit I will accept yours since you were first.

Answer (score 2):

The global `$authordata` variable is only available by default when [`$wp_query->is_author() && isset($wp_query->post)` condition](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L583) is satisfied.

It means that you can't access `$authordata` inside a single post page.

You may try to get author data via `$wp_query`:

```
add_action('wp_head', function()
{
    global $wp_query;

    $userdata   = get_userdata($wp_query->post->post_author);
    $avatar_url = get_avatar_ur($userdata->user_email);
    ...
}, 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the paste has worked perfect for you, let me turn it into an answer.

You can always get the author of a given post with certain methods, let's use `get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id )` for this.

To get the data of a given user, there's [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) function to use. We'll pass the author ID as first param to this function to get the author data outside the loop and where the post data are set:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'mine');
function mine() {
  if ( !is_single() )
    return; // this is not a single post

  if ( empty( ( $author = (int) get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_ID() ) ) ) )
    return; // no author was caught

  $authordata = get_userdata( $author );

  $avatar_url = get_avatar_url($authordata->user_email);
  // ....
}
```

This will always work as long as the single post' type is `post`. To expand to pages, call `is_page()`, or to custom post types `is_singular()`